# Mongoose : usr.findOneAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error : usr.findOneAndUpdate is not a function

#### Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, require: true },
    username: { type: String, require: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    creation_dt: { type: String, require: true },
    tasks:[{type:{type:String}}]
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',schema)
```

i want to Add some Task in tasks array so i use post method for That and code is

#### Code:

```
router.post('/newTask', function (req, res, next) {
  var dataa = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime
  }

  var usr = new User(req.user)
  usr.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id:req.user._id},
    {$push:{tasks:dataa}}
  )
  try {
    doc = usr.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }
})
```

i also read the documentation of findOneAndUpdate but i din't get solution please someone can Help out of this error....
Thank You.

Comment: [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) is a model's function, in your case User.

Comment: so what i suppose to change in code? @Victor

Comment: Have you defined the `User` in your controller?

Comment: Yess i import User schema in controller @KamNadimi

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your model into the file containing your routes. All mongoose methods are based off the schema that you define, not new instances you create.

For example, if you have a User model that looks like this:

```
// file is named user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

You need to import the model so mongoose recognizes it as one

Like so (assuming the routes file and user model file are in the same directory):

```
const User = require("./user")

router.post("/newTask", (req, res) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(//whatever you want to be updated)
})
```

Comment: I already added schema at the First of controller and also import mongoose. i know mongoose is not required but i think its error because of mongoose so i import both...Mongoose and my User schema

Comment: You have to use the User schema for the update method to work though, you pass the user that you want to update as the first parameter, then what you want to be updated within that user as the second.